# How to integrate Outlook tasks in OneNote for Mac users?

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-onenote-2016

I am trying to integrate Outlook tasks and OneNote. I'm a mac user, and OneNote does not appear under the "add-ins" in Outlook.

Here's a guide for how to do it for PC. 
https://business.tutsplus.com/tutorials/use-onenote-with-outlook-calendar--cms-31563

Do you know whether this is possible for Mac users? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, the “Send to OneNote” feature is available to Office 365 subscribers. You can go to Outlook->About Outlook and check if it the license is Office 365 Subscription.

If not, please try to re-sign in Outlook for Mac using the Office 365 for Business account. Meanwhile, make sure that the Outlook for Mac client is up to date. Y